# auto pause mediaelement.js audio player when playing new track

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

using the mediaelement.js audio - Does anyone know how or if it's possible to have 1 track pause automatically when another is played when there are 2 or more audio tracks on the same page? (I guess like a play/pause toggle attribute)

there's an example of what I'm talking about here using a flash player: http://stockmusicboutique.com/background but was wondering if it would be possible with this html 5 player.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
<audio src="track1.mp3" />
<audio src="track2.mp3" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  // make an array for the mediaelement players
  mediaElementPlayers = new Array();

  // run mediaelement.js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
          success:function(mediaElement, domObject){

              // add this mediaelement to the mediaElementPlayers array
              mediaElementPlayers.push(mediaElement);

              // bind the play event to the pauseAllPlayers function
              mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function(e){
                  pauseAllPlayers(e.target); }
              )
          }
      })
  })    

  // iterate through the mediaElementPlayers array, pause all players except the one that triggered the event.
  function pauseAllPlayers(currentPlayer){
      for(i=0; i<mediaElementPlayers.length; i++){
          if(mediaElementPlayers[i] != currentPlayer){
              mediaElementPlayers[i].pause();
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```